# Reverse last 2 chars of a String

Tags: java, strings, array

I have this problem:
Given a `String` of any length, return a new `String` where the last 2 chars, if present, are swapped. My question is, is there a more delicate way to do this than this way:

```
public String lastTwo(String str) {
   if(str.length() < 2 || str.equals("")){
      return str;
   }
   String lastTwo = str.substring(str.length() - 2);
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(lastTwo);
   String lastTwoReversed = sb.reverse().toString();
   return str.substring(0, str.length() - 2) + lastTwoReversed;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to swap the last two UTF-16 code units (possibly yielding an invalid string) or do you want to swap the last two graphemes (characters as the user perceives them)?

Comment: E.g. should the reversal of the string `""` yield `""` or `"��"`? It currently does the latter.

Comment: @heinrich5991 Your comment shows emojis on android mobile app : http://i.imgur.com/5xGWnTB.jpg . I dont know if should be commented in meta

Comment: @rpax These are emojis from Unicode, I believe it is intended that they're rendered this way on Android. Maybe I should pick different symbols.

Comment: @heinrich5991 Great point.  If there is any chance at all your input string could contain surrogate-pair characters, this approach does not handle it, and you will need to use something like `String.codePointCount`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rather than generating the substring for the last two chars and reversing it, you could simply add the last two chars in reverse order:

```
return str.substring(0, str.length() - 2)
    + str.charAt(str.length() - 1)
    + str.charAt(str.length() - 2);
```

Comment: Don't you think the string concatenation would reduce performance?

Comment: @TopinFrassi: Have you profiled it? Is this a bottleneck?

Comment: @VincentSavard Nope, I didn't profile it! I know that, in theory, string concatenation is slower than using the `StringBuilder`. But in such a small case, maybe there'd be an overhead. Hence why I asked the question :p

Comment: @TopinFrassi Don't know. I suppose this could also be `new StringBuilder(str.substr(0, str.length() - 2).append(str[str.length() - 1]).append(str[str.length() - 2]).toString();`, I don't know which is faster (or if it matters in this context).

Comment: @Barry Java (whether by the standard or just by the JVM I do not know) turns string addition into `StringBuilder` calls as you wrote, so as long as it's in one expression the two are equivalent.

Comment: @Veedrac This is done by the Java compiler.

Comment: What's up with the indexing strings with brackets?

Comment: @user2357112 I assume it's not Java, Java doesnt have the method `substr()` in String. It's `substring()`. Also this will throw `IndexOutOfBounds` if length is less than 2.

Comment: @WalterM No it would not since this is suppose to replace the last 4 lines of codes in the original question, the validation is still there to check for the length.

Comment: @user2357112 Because that's how normal languages do basic operations. But fixed to `charAt` because I guess brevity is overrated.

Answer (score 8):

The second condition here

> ```
> if(str.length() < 2 || str.equals("")){
>    return str;
> }
> ```

is superflous. How should `str` be equal to `""` and having `>= 2` characters ?

The multiple calls to `str.length()` can be reduced to one call by storing the result in a variable.

Using a `StringBuilder` for concating 2 characters is a little bit over the top. I guess the creation of the `StringBuilder` will take more time and memory than just adding the chars.

Answer (score 5):

I would check if the `String` is `null` first and either throw  `IllegalArgumentException` and explain that the `String` must not be `null` or I would do nothing and return `null`. It's yours to decide which is better depending on what you need.

`lastTwo` is not the best name for your method since it's not really description on what the method is doing. Try to find a better way like : `reverseLastTwoCharacters` or something like that.

Comment: What if there is only one character? That would error, it is not null but it is also not valid.

Comment: It's already covered in the code : `if(str.length() < 2 || str.equals("")){  return str;`

Answer (score 2):

### Using regex

You can make use of capturing groups to do the reversing. The regex to match the pattern you are looking for is `(.)(.)$`. This implies to match the last two characters

In code it looks like this:

```
str.replaceFirst("(.)(.)$", "$2$1")
```

The symbols `$1`, `$2`, simply refer to each of those brackets you have placed in the initial regex. So this means that to accomplish what you want, you simply interchange the positions of the `$1` and `$2` and the swapping is complete.

### Putting it all together

```
public String reverseLastTwo(String str) {
   if(str != null){
      return str.replaceFirst("(.)(.)$", "$2$1");
   }
   return str;
}
```

Comment: `-1` - not enough jQuery. More seriously though: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/10999/88637 http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/ etc using RegEx in such trivial case hogs both CPU/mem and programmer's brainpower... if I see `str.substr(0, len - 2) + str.charAt(len - 1) + str.charAt(len - 2);`, I can tell what it does *in milliseconds*. When I see `str.replaceFirst("(.)(.)$", "$2$1");`, *I actually have to decode the regex first*. First notation can be understood by *any* person with *any* programming background - second *forces* you to know regex.

Comment: @vaxquis I think the word you are looking for is `documentation`, besides there is enough context behind this code that you don't even need to know what the regex does to understand what the code is doing. It is well known fact that if you didn't write the code then there is a high chance you will not understand it. Also what dictates trivial code? This code is trivial to me, what does that mean?

Comment: obligatory https://xkcd.com/1343/ - the word you are looking for is [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) - if the regex code appeared outside of a single method dedicated for it, I highly doubt if the intention would be as clear. It's not my opinion that regexes are [Write Once, Run Away](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-only_language) code. Also, `It is well known fact that if you didn't write the code then there is a high chance you will not understand it.` **{citation needed} {weasel words}** BTW, `what does [trivial] mean?` http://www.thefreedictionary.com/trivial

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much you can do if it's a String, at the very least you will have to copy the entire string again. You can use a StringBuilder for the variable that you want to change, but Note that every time you call toString() it returns a new String meaning `str.toString() == str.toString()` will always be false.

```
public StringBuilder lastTwo(CharSequence str, boolean allowModify){
    //if allowModify is true then we can change the StringBuilder and save precious CPU time.
    //otherwise we create a new StringBuilder
    StringBuilder builder = !allowModify || !(str instanceof StringBuilder) ? new StringBuilder(str) : (StringBuilder)str;

    final int strLen = str.length();
    if (strLen >= 2) {
        //simple swap
        char lastChar = builder.charAt(strLen - 1);
        builder.setCharAt(strLen - 1, builder.charAt(strLen - 2));
        builder.setCharAt(strLen - 2, lastChar);
    }
    return builder;
}
```

To explain what it's doing

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("123");
String str2 = "123";

System.out.printf("%-9s %-9s%n", "New", "Original");
System.out.printf("%-9s %-9s%n", lastTwo(str, false), str);
System.out.printf("%-9s %-9s%n", lastTwo(str2, false), str2);
System.out.println("Allow Modify");
System.out.printf("%-9s %-9s%n", lastTwo(str, true), str);
System.out.printf("%-9s %-9s%n", lastTwo(str2, true), str2);
```

Output

```
New       Original 
132       123      
132       123      
Allow Modify
132       132      //original is changed here as it is a StringBuilder
132       123      //this is a String, so it will remain
```